# Rotating certain particles in a particle system in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, particles

I'm working on a visual effect using particle systems.

I'm trying to rotate newly created particles according to some object's velocity at that time.

Currently, I'm rotating the entire particle system and I use the "Align To Direction" option in the "Shape" options.

It works fine, until I change the velocity of the object - then it rotates every existing particle too.

How can I rotate particles when they are created?

Comment: What simulation space are you using?

Comment: World (the game im doing this in, is also 2D btw)